# Adding new Wagtail CMS Snippets

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I would like to add new Wagtail Snippet models but cannot find any documentation regarding proper file naming to begin building them; do I place them in my apps `model.py` file or does it have a specific method similar to `wagtailadmin`?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippets are common django models, which are registered using a decorator function. Therefore they live in `models.py`.

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.wagtailsnippets.models import register_snippet

@register_snippet
class Foobar(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```

If your app grows you might consider using a package instead of a module. Create a folder called models and copy the contents of `models.py` into a file called `__init__.py`.
Afterwards create separate modules. E.g. `snippets.py` inside of this new folder and import them inside of `__init__.py`

Sample code:

**`models/__init__.py`**:

```
from .snippets import *
```

**`models/snippets.py`**:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.wagtailsnippets.models import register_snippet

@register_snippet
class Foobar(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=3)
```